# How to loop over hostnames or IPs in ansible

Tags: ansible

Am trying to set up and configure pacemaker using Ansible playbook in Ubuntu 14.04.

As of now, am just testing it in one node. Hence in hosts file I just kept the information of that node

```
[hostname]
1.2.3.4   ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ubuntu/test.pem
```

In the playbook YAML file am trying to install as well as configure pacemaker

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install pacemaker
      apt: name=pacemaker state=present
    - name: install corosync
      apt: name=corosync state=present
    - name: install fence-agents
      apt: name=fence-agents state=present
    #- copy: src=corosync_start dest=/etc/default/corosync
    #- shell: update-rc.d -f pacemaker remove
    #- shell: update-rc.d pacemaker start 50 1 2 3 4 5 . stop 01 0 6 .
```

Installation is taking place properly in my node. But for configuration, I need to edit /etc/corosync/corosync.conf in which i need to specify my Host address in place of `bindnetaddress`.

Say I am having more than one entry under [hostname] section - is there any way in Ansible that I can loop over them in my YAML file?

I am trying to use sed command to replace the IP. Can you please explain how to loop over or print the IPs?

I tried like this

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: msg = "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - name: Test
      task: {% for host in groups['app_servers'] %}
            {{host}}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: have you tried with loop in ansible over your host groups? {% for host in groups['app_servers'] %}
 //do task using {{host}}
{% endfor %}

Comment: am not sure about the syntax. am new to this. Can you pls write the above in yaml format as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for confusing you with my comment,
Assuming you have inventory file

```
    [ALL]
host1.com
host2.com
```

your yaml file should look like this (using with_items)

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install pacemaker
      apt: name=pacemaker state=present
    - name: install corosync
      apt: name=corosync state=present
    - name: install fence-agents
      apt: name=fence-agents state=present
    - copy: src=corosync_start dest=/etc/default/corosync
    - lineinfile: dest=/etc/selinux/config line="my host {{ item }}"
      with_items: groups['ALL']
```

Just rememeber it will create each line for each host
**I think what are you looking for is acctually not looping but getting current host name (ansible_hostname):**

```
 - hosts: all
      sudo: yes
      gather_facts: yes
      tasks:
        - name: install pacemaker
          apt: name=pacemaker state=present
        - name: install corosync
          apt: name=corosync state=present
        - name: install fence-agents
          apt: name=fence-agents state=present
        - copy: src=corosync_start dest=/etc/default/corosync
        - lineinfile: dest=/etc/selinux/config line="my host {{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

Comment: I think the groups['ALL'] does not work as it is case sensitive.
Should someone want to use this I think it should be groups['all']

Answer (score 6):

Something along these lines should work:

```
- debug: msg="host is {{ item }}"
  with_items:  groups['app_servers']
```

This will give you the name of each host as defined in your inventory.  If you want the FQDN as provided by an Ansible fact (or any other facts for the host) then you want to do something like this:

```
- debug: msg="host is {{ hostvars[item]['inventory_hostname'] }}"
  with_items:  "{{ groups['app_servers'] }}"
```

Comment: This generates the same results as the `inventory_hostnames` lookup plugin as far as I can see, and is more concise.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this official module created by ansible.
Like this

## show all the hosts in the inventory

`- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all`

Reference Link
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-the-inventory